# using sparklyr in RStudio, can I upload a LOCAL csv file to a spark cluster

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio, sparkr

I'm pretty new to cluster computing, so not sure if this is even possible.

I am successfully creating a `spark_context` in Rstudio (using sparklyr) to connect to our local Spark cluster. Using `copy_to` I can upload data frames from R to Spark, but I am trying to upload a locally stored CSV file directly to the Spark cluster using `spark_read_csv` without importing it into the R environment first (it's a big 5GB file). It's not working (even prefixing location with file:///), and it seems that it can only upload files that are ALREADY stored in the cluster.

How do I upload a local file directly to spark without loading it into R first??

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Are you receiving an error?  What is happening that you say it is 'not working'?

Comment: it's a 'file not found' error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. File has to be reachable from each machine in your cluster either as a local copy or placed on distributed files system / object storage.

Comment: Is there any other way to upload large files into Spark from external sources? I am also attempting to read data into spark from cassandra via RStudio, and failing at that as well (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877859/unable-to-connect-spark-to-cassandra-db-in-rstudio)

Comment: `--files`? But then you have to use `spark.getSparkFiles` to figure out the path and it is not very efficient.

Comment: how would i go about doing that in R?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the files from local to spark by using `spark_read_csv()` method. Please pass the path properly.

Note: It is not necessary to load the data first into R environment.

Comment: using this method it is only possible to upload csv files which are 'local' to the cluster, not local to the remote machine which is running R.