# Unable to connect Spark to Cassandra DB in RStudio

Tags: r, apache-spark, cassandra, rstudio, sparklyr

I've spent the last week trying to figure out how to use sparlyr to get spark to connect to cassandra on our local cluster, and I've hit a wall - any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm the only one trying to use R/Rstudio to make this connection (everyone else uses Java on NetBeans and Maven), and am not sure what I need to do to make this work.

The stack I'm using is:
Ubuntu 16.04 (in a VM)
sparklyr: 0.5.3
Spark: 2.0.0
Scala: 2.11
Cassandra: 3.7

relevant config.yml file settings:

```
# cassandra settings
spark.cassandra.connection.host: <cluster_address>
spark.cassandra.auth.username: <user_name>
spark.cassandra.auth.password: <password>

sparklyr.defaultPackages:
- com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0
- com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.0.0-M1
- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:3.0.2
```

Sys.setnev setting set for local install of Java and spark, config set to use yml file. Spark connection initiated with:

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "spark://<cluster_address>", config = spark_config(file = "config.yml"))
```

Spark session initiated with:

```
sparkSession <- sparklyr::invoke_static(sc, org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession", "builder") %>% 
    sparklyr::invoke("config", "spark.cassandra.connection.host", "<cluster_address>") %>% 
    sparklyr::invoke("getOrCreate")
```

It all seems fine up to here, (sc connection and sparkSession), but now attempting to access a cassandra table (table_1 in in keyspace_1), which I know exists:

```
cass_df <- invoke(sparkSession, "read") %>% 
invoke("format", "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") %>% 
invoke("option", "keyspace", "keyspace_1") %>% 
invoke("option", "table", "table_1") %>% 
invoke("load")
```

throws up the following error:

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot build a cluster without contact points
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.checkNotEmpty(Cluster.java:123)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.(Cluster.java:116)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:182)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:1274)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.createCluster(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:92) . . .
```

Comment: Missing `spark.cassandra.connection.host`?

Comment: yes! that was just the hint i needed. when initiating my sparkSession I was using the SPARK <cluster_address> (with port number) rather than just the cluster address (where cassandra was located). it works! thanks @user7337271.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solved it, thanks to a useful tip.I was using the SPARK  (with port number) to initialise the SparkSession rather than just the cluster address (where cassandra was located). it works! thanks @user7337271.